# Unable to connect to server: Starbucks wifi and newly installed Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, windows, thinkpad

Ok, so last night I went ahead with adding Ubuntu to my yoga thinkpad along side Windows 8.1  I love it.  Wifi works at home but I decided to drive over to Starbucks today to get some writing work done and the wifi would connect but when I load up firefox it just says unable to connect to server.  I know that Starbucks has some sort of portal and users have to accept their terms before being able to go online but I couldn't even get to that page.  The portal address would show up in my browser but I get the unable to connect to server page.

Info:

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Windows 8.1
lenovo Thinkpad Yoga
```

I'm a complete n00b in every aspect but I'm more than willing to learn and I'm sort of throwing myself in it hoping to swim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try opening up a terminal and running:

```
sudo dhclient
```

A lot of these public wifi spots use weird hacky ways to get that portal screen to pop up and I find that Linux often does not automatically get an IP address.

Running that command should basically request a new IP from the DHCP server at Starbucks. Usually that does the trick for me.